# Scroll to top unoticably or crop top overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This question is a little hard to explain: I have an image at the bottom of a page. On click of that image I load the next page via ajax without removing that image. How can I crop out or remove all the space above the image? Or, maybe a better way to put it is how do I scroll to top unnoticeably?

[Here is perfect example](https://bonnemarque.se/case/jdco/) of what I'm trying to accomplish - go to the bottom of the page and see what happens when you click the image. What is the concept behind that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you specifically what that website is doing.

They have each page in a container called `<div class="page-container">`. When you click the bottom link, a new `<div class="page-container">` is added with a css `top` property that pushes it off the bottom of the screen and both page containers are set to `position:absolute`.

The `top` css properties of both page containers are animated with a Javascript timer until the first `<div class="page-container">` is pushed off the top of the  screen, then the first page container is removed from the DOM.

At the same time the page containers are moving via manipulated `top` property, the scrollbar position is animated so it moves along with the containers. After the animation is done and the new page container is set to `position:relative`, the scrollbar is at the top of the screen again.

Here is a rough example using jQuery for convenience https://jsfiddle.net/0bzt9mmq/

Comment: Works great! Thanks. Would you have any heads up on cross-browser/mobile support? Things to watch out for with this approach?

Comment: I can't think of anything off the top of my head other than most phones will barf on you when you try to animate CSS properties with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this. 
https://jsfiddle.net/vh60oycj/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#container{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.img_elems{
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.pages{
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
}

.label{
  width:  20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.move{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: slide; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: slide;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0%   { top: 100%}
    100% { top: 0;}
}

@keyframes slide {
    0%   { top: 100%}
    100% { top: 0;}
}

.fade{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0%   { opacity : 0;}
    100% { opacity : 1;}
}
```

**JS**

```
var get_some_images =  "https://placehold.it/640x480";
var get_container = document.getElementById("container");

init(11);

//function that create the it
function create_img_elem(content,index){
    var new_elem = document.createElement("div");
  var label = document.createElement("div");
    new_elem.className = "img_elems";
  new_elem.id = "img_elem"+index;
  new_elem.style.background = "url('"+ content +"') no-repeat center";
  new_elem.setAttribute("data-elem-num", index);

  label.className = "label";
  label.id = "label" + index;
  label.innerHTML = "#" + index;

  new_elem.appendChild(label)
  get_container.appendChild(new_elem);
}

//function that create the elem
function create_page(content,index){
    var new_elem = document.createElement("div");
  var label = document.createElement("div");
    new_elem.className = "pages";
  new_elem.id = "page" + index;
  new_elem.innerHTML = content;
  new_elem.setAttribute("data-elem-num", index);
  get_container.appendChild(new_elem);
  $( "#page" + index).addClass("fade");
}

function click_event (clicked_img){

   //getting all the elements on container
     var array_elems = $('#container').children();

   //getting data attributes "data-elem-num" of clicked_element
   var clicked_elem = clicked_img[0].attributes[2].value;

   //store "data-elem-num" attr
   var elem_ids;

   for(var j = 0, len_elems = array_elems.length; j <len_elems;j++){
     elem_ids = array_elems[j].attributes[2].value;

     //store "data-elem-num" attr
     if(elem_ids !== clicked_elem){
      //instead of fadeout from jquery, you can do css animation. better animation that way
        $( "#img_elem" + elem_ids).fadeOut("fast");

     }else{
         create_page("this is about element " + clicked_elem, clicked_elem);
        $("#img_elem" + clicked_elem).addClass('move fade').css("pointer-events", "none");
     }

   }
}

function init(amount_of_elements){
  for(var i=0, len = amount_of_elements; i < len; i++){
    create_img_elem(get_some_images,i)
  }
  $(".img_elems").click(function(){
    click_event ($(this));
  });
}
```

I'm accessing the DOM Object that's been click and looping through to see if any of match my clicked items. if not hide them, afterwords fadein the element and any
additional elements. I know you already have solution, this more resources I guess.

Comment: Maybe you could provide an explanation of this design because I don't understand what's supposed to be happening when you click on a box in Chrome, also definitely not working in Firefox, IE.